# Nest query for elastic n gram filter and analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, n-gram

I have created filters and analyzers on my elastic db. Can i use them directly or do i need to provide settings in my Nest query.

```
POST /myindextest/_close

PUT myindextest/_settings
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "trigrams_filter": {
                    "type": "ngram",
                    "min_gram": 3,
                    "max_gram": 3
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "trigrams": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "trigrams_filter"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "mappings": {
        "myindextest": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "trigrams"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

POST /myindextest/_open
```

If i have to provide them in C# using **NEST** then how **filters and analyzers should be created and assigned to specific queries**? Where i can find a better documentation for Elastic NEST.

Comment: You can use them directly using attribute ([ElasticProperty(IndexAnalyzer = "partial_name", SearchAnalyzer = "full_name")]) in the c# class. You can specify them at querry time if needed by using .Analyzer( at the same place than the querry.

Comment: Check out the documentation on analysis with NEST: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/analysis.html